# How to change dynamically bsConfig in BsDaterangepickerDirective (NGX date range picker)

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

**Template Code**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" #drp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker [(bsConfig)]="customBsConfig">
```

**Typescript Code**

```
@ViewChild('drp') dataRangePicker: BsDaterangepickerDirective;
customBsConfig: object;

ngOnInit() {
    this.translate.use().subscribe(
        () => {
            this.customBsConfig = Object.assign({}, {
                rangeInputFormat: "MMM-dd-yyyy"
            });
            this.dataRangePicker.setConfig();
        }
    }
);
```

[Date Range Picker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#triggers-custom) works fine however I need to change the bsConfig dynamically. (Here I'm using the ngx translate service. So when the languages get dynamically loaded the rangeInputFormat of the date range picker also should applied/updated ). How to achieve this? Is it possible ?

Comment: Probably not like that. Why are you using `Object.assign` ? simply set the value with an equal ... And it should be updated, since you send this object as an @Input to the library. Why are you calling `setConfig`  ? if you do so, shouldn't you send the config with it ?

Comment: @trichetriche I followed https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#config-method

Comment: Oh god that's aweful ... Well sorry then, I can't help you with that (except strongly recommend using another lbrary :D)

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales

Comment: @Nalaka526 Thanks but I'm looking for more like dynamically apply configs to the date range picker. Especially, the rangeInputFormat only.

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda, Accept or comment on the answer, if you feel useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took 3hours of debugging to figure the workaround:

```
@ViewChild('dataRangePicker') dataRangePicker: BsDaterangepickerDirective;
customBsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig> = new BsDatepickerConfig();
dateRange: Date[];
range = {
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date()
};

format = {
  "en-us" : 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  "en-gb" : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  "ge": "DD.MM.YYYY"
};

constructor() {
    this.calanderConfigInit();
}

ngOnChanges() {
    this.translate.use().subscribe(
        (langChanged) => {
            this.calanderConfigChange();
        });
}

selectDate() {
    this.range.start = this.dateRange[0] 
    this.range.end = this.dateRange[1]
}

calanderConfigInit() {
    const langChoosen = "en-us"; // get current language;
    this.environmentBS.rangeInputFormat = format[langChoosen];
}

calanderconfigChange() {
  // clear the ngmodel of datepicker and re-assign it same values which we stored earlier during change event.
  this.dateRange = [];
  this.dateRange = [this.range.start,this.range.end];

  // required format based on condition.
  this.customBsConfig.rangeInputFormat = format[langChanged];
  this.dataRangePicker.setConfig();
}
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="class" bsDaterangepicker
       #dataRangePicker="bsDaterangepicker" [(ngModel)]="dateRange"
       (ngModelChange)="selectDate()" [maxDate]="maxDate"
       [minDate]='minDate' [bsConfig]="customBsConfig">
```

Comment: You can't imagine, how much I thank you! Life saver.

Comment: Thanks, man I was wondering how to change min date, and inspired by this solution finally solved an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the sample example for the ngx dateRangePicker dynamic instance

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-daterangepicker